# How to use dataclasses to generate a field value?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I have the following class:

```
class WordItem:
    def __init__(self, phrase: str, word_type: WORD_TYPE):
        self.id = f'{phrase}_{word_type.name.lower()}'
        self.phrase = phrase
        self.word_type = word_type

    @classmethod
    def from_payload(cls, payload: Dict[str, Any]) -> 'WordItem':
        return cls(**payload)
```

How can I rewrite this class as a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html)?

Specifically, how should the `id` field be declared? It has a generated value, and is not a field that the code creating instances would provide.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just move each of your attributes to a type-annotated declaration on the class, where the class has been decorated with the [`@dataclasses.dataclass` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass).

You can generate the value for `id` in a [`__post_init__` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing); make sure you mark it as exempt from the `__init__` arguments with a [`dataclass.field()` object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field    

@dataclass
class WordItem:
    id: str = field(init=False)
    phrase: str
    word_type: WORD_TYPE

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = f'{self.phrase}_{self.word_type.name.lower()}'
```

Demo:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> wt = SimpleNamespace(name='Python')
>>> WordItem('await', wt)
WordItem(id='await_python', phrase='await', word_type=namespace(name='Python'))
```

Comment: what if my prev implementation had the following method:
    @classmethod
    def from_payload(cls, payload: Dict[str, Any]) -> 'WordItem':
        return cls(**payload)

how can I use it?

Comment: @petrush: please don't move the goal posts. Class methods work no different on dataclasses; the example in my question essentially generates the same `__init__` method as before, you can add class methods to that class just the same.

Comment: So your classmethod would work exactly as written; you can put `from_payload` on the dataclass without any changes and it'll continue to work.

Comment: To generate IDs you can also use default fields. E.g. `id: str = field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))`

Comment: @JVillella: sure, but that's not what is being asked here. You can't access other field values there.