# Dataclass: NameError: name 'WORD_TYPE' is not defined

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I tried to work with SO question example

```
@dataclass
class WordItem:
    id: str = field(init=False)
    phrase: str
    word_type: WORD_TYPE

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = f'{self.phrase}_{self.word_type.name.lower()}'
```

I got

```
<ipython-input-3-df20e5b35c67> in WordItem()
      3     id: str = field(init=False)
      4     phrase: str
----> 5     word_type: WORD_TYPE
      6 
      7     def __post_init__(self):

NameError: name 'WORD_TYPE' is not defined
```

My Python version

```
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

What is exactly WORD_TYPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627942/how-to-use-dataclasses-to-generate-a-field-value) you're referring to has this missing I believe, which is to define a custom type before the class definition.

```
from typing import NewType
WORD_TYPE = NewType('WORD_TYPE', str)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes) is a better example to work through for `dataclasses`. I would also recommend you use Python 3.7 and its [native dataclasses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).